# Calculate $\lim_{n\to\infty} n^{\gamma} \int_{-1/n}^{1/n} |f(x)| dx$.

Tags: calculus, integration, measure-theory

Let $p > 1$ and define $I_n = (-1/n, 1/n)$. Suppose $\gamma \leq \frac{p-1}{p}$ and $f \in L^P(I_2)$.

I want to calculate $\lim_{n\to\infty} n^{\gamma} \int_{I_n} |f(x)| dx$.

Let $q$ be the Holder conjugate of $p$ such that $1/p + 1/q = 1$. Notice that this means $1/q = \frac{p-1}{p} \geq \gamma$. So, $ n^{\gamma} \int_{I_n} |f(x)| dx \leq \int_{I_n} n^{1/q}|f(x)| dx$. Applying Holder's inequality, we get that this is at most $2^{1/q} (\int_{I_n} |f|^p )^{1/p}$.

I'm stuck when it comes to calculating $\lim_{n\to\infty} (\int_{I_n} |f|^p )^{1/p}$. My guess is that this would go to zero, as the interval we are integrating over shrinks to a single point (of measure zero), but I'm unable to show this rigorously.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define
$$ f_n(x)=\chi_{I_n}(x)|f(x)|^p,x\in I_2 $$
and then $$ |f_n(x)|\le |f(x)|^p, x\in I_2. $$
Noting that $$\lim_{n\to\infty}f_n(x)=0, \int_{I_2}|f(x)|^pdx<\infty $$
by the DCT, one has
$$ \lim_{n\to\infty}\int_{I_n}|f(x)|^pdx=\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_{I_2}\chi_{I_n}(x)|f(x)|^pdx=\int_{I_2}\lim_{n\to\infty}\chi_{I_n}(x)|f(x)|^pdx=0$$
and hence
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}n^{\gamma}\int_{I_2}|f(x)|^pdx=0$$